# How to create a jQuery reusable function with cookie?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a reusable function with jQuery which will allow me to use multiple bootstrap alert in a page and save the state via cookie for each of them.

HTML:

```
<p class="alert alert-box"> mytext message<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button></p>
```

JS:

```
   jQuery(function( $ ){

    // Check if the alert has been closed
    if( $.cookie('alert-box') === 'closed' ){

        $('.alert').hide();

    }

    // lets do the code binding here
    // Grab your button 
    $('.close').click(function( e ){

        // Do not perform default action when button is clicked
        e.preventDefault();

        /* If you just want the cookie for a session don't provide an expires
         Set the path as root, so the cookie will be valid across the whole site */
        $.cookie('alert-box', 'closed', { path: '/' });

    });

});
```

I'm guessing I need to use the

```
 $this
```

but I have no idea how to implement it.

Comment: `$(this).closest('.alert-box').hide();`

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you want to do. You mention you want a cookie for each alert, but you've only got one cookie. Also, you're setting this one cookie to 'closed' when you close the alert, but never clearing the cookie. So, once an alert is closed, that's it for the remainder of the session.

Comment: I'm guessing you need to use 3 different cookies if you have 3 different alerts. Or can it be done with one cookie? Closed is fine as if the user closed the alert means he already got the info needed at that point..